# What is "accommodation" in phonetics?

Tags: terminology, phonetics, coarticulation

What is "accommodation" in English?  What types of accommodation are there?

I've tried to search in the Internet, but I could not find proper information.

Comment: I googled "phonetic accommodation" and got two (conflicting) definitions on the first page.

Comment: You must have been studying phonetics in Eastern Europe/Russia. The English equivalent is coarticulation.

Answer (score 2):

The other meaning, not meaning "coarticulation", refers to how people change their pronunciation depending on their audience. For instance, my native pronunciation of "root" is [rʊt], which is completely unknown to most non-native speakers, therefore is I ask for the word "root", I have to pronounce it [ruwt]. Likewise, two speakers may start to sound more like each other, depending on lots of social variables. [Here](http://linguistics.berkeley.edu/dissertations/Babel_dissertation_2009.pdf) is a dissertation on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

The phenomenon called 'phonetic accommodation' happens when people change the way they speak due to their interlocutors' speech.

On the other hand, 'assimilation' is a phonological process that occurs when a phoneme adopts some features of its neighbouring sounds (regressive/progressive assimilation).

Answer (score 0):

Accommodation is the modification in the articulation of a vowel under the influence of an adjacent sound, or the modification in the articulation of a consonant under the influence of an adjacent vowel.
Consonant + back vowel: pool, rude, who (rounded)
Consonant + front vowel: tea, sit, keep (spread)

Comment: /ɹ/ is not a good example, because it's inherently round in onset position, thus also in [ɹʷɪtʃ]; and "who" is ambiguous in dialects that contrast [w] and [ʍ]. Better examples would be "loose" vs. "lease".

Comment: More examples, please.